# Simulating fast swipe in my application on rooted device

Tags: android

I am using su command to simulate swipe in my application:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "adb 
            shell input touchscreen swipe" + " " + oldCoordinates[i] + 
            " " + oldCoordinates[i+1] + " " + newCoordinates[j] + " "
            + newCoordinates[j+1]});

p.waitFor();
```

But it is taking around 1 second to execute this command...
How can I increase the speed or is there any alternative by which I can simulate fast swipes???

Answer (score 0):

The best way to simulate swipe is using adb shell commands "sendevent".You can run these commands through library "EventInjector" made by Rado.Though the commands used in his library might be different for your device(eg:sendevent 2 0 2323)...
You can get the required commands from command::adb shell getevent.....::